# Better pure version of same_length/2

Tags: prolog, logical-purity

Given the frequent pure definition of `same_length/2` as

```
same_length([],[]).
same_length([_|As], [_|Bs]) :-
   same_length(As, Bs).

?- same_length(L, [_|L]).
   loops.
```

Is there a pure definition that does not loop for such cases?  Something in analogy to the pure (but less efficient) version of `append/3` called [`append2u/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65361752/772868).

I know how to catch such cases manually with `var/1` and the like, but ideally a version that is just as pure as the original definition would be desirable. Or at least it should be simple.

What I have tried is the definition above.

One clarification seems to be in order:

Note that there are certain queries that inherently must not terminate. Think of:

```
?- same_length(Ls, Ks).
   Ls = [], Ks = []
;  Ls = [_A], Ks = [_B]
;  Ls = [_A,_B], Ks = [_C,_D]
;  Ls = [_A,_B,_C], Ks = [_D,_E,_F]
;  Ls = [_A,_B,_C,_D], Ks = [_E,_F,_G,_H]
;  ... .
```

There is no other way to enumerate all solutions using the language of syntactic answer substitutions.

But still an implementation may terminate for the queries given.

Comment: Adding `same_length(L, L) :- \+ length(L, _), !, false.` has the first clause seems to solve the issue but it isn't pure.

Comment: ... if the occurs check is disabled.

Comment: Not even, see [#26](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/length#26) all systems either loop, produce a resource error, or produce a type error.

Comment: I don't think there's any hope for a general answer here. consider `A=[X|A], B=[X,Y|A]`, then consider `A=[X|A], B=[X,Y|A], X=Y`. plus, a cyclic list's prefix before the looping point can have _any_ length. a predicate which terminates must be correct first, isn't it? so at best you can hope for an *error* termination, it seems.

Answer (score 2):

This answer aims at minimising runtime costs.

It is built on `'$skip_max_list'/4` and runs on Scryer Prolog.

First up, some auxiliary code:

```
:- use_module(library(lists)).

'$skip_list'(N,Xs0,Xs) :-
   '$skip_max_list'(N,_,Xs0,Xs).

is_list([]).
is_list([_|Xs]) :-
   is_list(Xs).

sam_length_([],[]).
sam_length_([_|Xs],[_|Ys]) :-
   sam_length_(Xs,Ys).
```

Now the main dish:

```
sam_length(Ls1,Ls2) :-
   '$skip_list'(L1,Ls1,Rs1),
   (  Rs1 == []
   -> length(Ls2,L1)
   ;  var(Rs1),
      '$skip_max_list'(L2,L1,Ls2,Rs2),
      (  L2 < L1
      -> var(Rs2),
         Rs1 \== Rs2,
         '$skip_max_list'(_,L2,Ls1,Ps1),
         sam_length_(Ps1,Rs2)
      ;  '$skip_list'(N2,Rs2,Ts2),
         (  Ts2 == []
         -> M1 is N2-L1,
            length(Rs1,M1)
         ;  var(Ts2),
            (  N2 > 0
            -> Ts2 \== Rs1,
               sam_length_(Rs2,Rs1)     % switch argument order
            ;  Rs1 == Rs2
            -> is_list(Rs1)             % simpler enumeration
            ;  sam_length_(Rs1,Rs2)
            )
         )
      )
   ).
```

Sample queries:

```
?- sam_length(L,[_|L]).
   false.
?- sam_length([_],L).
   L = [_A].
?- sam_length(L,M).
   L = [], M = []
;  L = [_A], M = [_B]
;  ... .
```

Comment: Purity oh purity, where art thou?

Comment: @false. Pure behaviour or pure code?

Comment: ... **and** ...

Comment: @false. AFAIK pure behaviour is the best we can get if we need `(==)/2`.

Comment: No `if_/3` anywhere near?

Comment: Not really happy to award this bounty, I hoped for something purer.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `'$skip_max_list'/4`:

```
% Clause for `?- L = [a|L], same_length(L, _)`.
same_length(As, Bs) :-
    (Cs = As ; Cs = Bs),
    '$skip_max_list'(_, _, Cs, Cs0),
    subsumes_term([_|_], Cs0), !,
    false.
% Clause for `?- same_length(L, [_|L])`.
same_length(As, Bs) :-
    As \== Bs,
    '$skip_max_list'(S, _, As, As0),
    '$skip_max_list'(T, _, Bs, Bs0),
    As0 == Bs0,
    S \== T, !,
    false.
same_length(As, Bs) :-
    same_length_(As, Bs).

same_length_([], []).
same_length_([_|As], [_|Bs]) :-
   same_length_(As, Bs).
```

Queries:

```
?- L = [a|L], same_length(L, _).
   false.
?- same_length(L, [_|L]).
   false.
?- same_length([_], L).
   L = [_A].
?- same_length(L, M).
   L = [], M = []
;  L = [_A], M = [_B]
;  ... .
```

Comment: I like `subsumes_term([_|_], Cs0)` which indeed merits to be compiled into `nonvar(Cs0), Cs0 = [_|_]`

Comment: And that you do not utilize the `Max` ...

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED SOLUTION**

Here is my solution:

```
same_length(A, A).
same_length([_|A], [_|B]) :- same_length(A, B).
    
?- same_length(L, [_|L]).
  L = [_1696|L]
```

I am not sure if it has all the properties you're looking for. For example if you call

```
? - same_length(L, [1,2,3]).
```

then it lists many answers, e.g. L = [_X, 2, 3], rather than just [_X, _Y, _Z]. But it's pure and produces a correct answer for the query quoted.

Comment: `same_length(L, [_|L]).` should fail, but your version produces infinitely many answers.

Comment: `?- same_length([1],[2]).
   true
;  true, unexpected.` This produces a redundant solution.

Comment: Thanks for reviewing the solution!
I've updated it.
Now there is no redundant solution for your second example.
And for the first one, it actually should not fail. Prolog supports infinite lists to some extent.
So when we get a solution `L = [_1696|L]` it means that L is an infinite list containing the same element, which is true.
As for the fact that the number solution is infinite, it's not ideal, I agree.

Comment: There is  still`?- same_length([1],[1]). true ; true.`

Comment: *Prolog supports infinite lists to some extent.* This is not really the issue. The major problem is that your program (with or without infinite lists) does not terminate, just like the original program. And I want this to improve. Also, in the original program there is no space whatsoever for a solution like `L = [_|L]`. It just loops.

Comment: I forgot `same_length(non_list, non_list)` which should not succeed.

Answer (score 1):

This is reasonably elegant, but with performance degradation:

```
% Using a previously-seen-tails list
same_length2(L, M) :-
    same_length2_(L, M, []).

same_length2_([], [], _).
% P is list of tails previously visited
same_length2_([HL|L], [HM|M], P) :-
    same_length2_chk_([HL|L], P),
    same_length2_chk_([HM|M], P),
    % Append after checking, to never see again
    append([[HL|L], [HM|M]], P, P1),
    same_length2_(L, M, P1).

same_length2_chk_(T, P) :-
    % Ensure no match with previously-seen tails
    \+ (
        member(E, P),
        T == E
    ).
```

Results in swi-prolog:

```
?- same_length2([_|L], [_|L]).
L = [] ;
L = [_] ;
L = [_, _] ;

?- length(L, 10_000_000), time(same_length2(L, [])).
% 3 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (88% CPU, 153249 Lips)
false.

?- freeze(R, R=[_|L]), same_length2(L, R).
false.

?- L = [_|L], same_length2(L, []).
false.

?- same_length2([1,2|L], [3,4,5|L]).
false.

?- same_length2(L, [_|L]).
false.

?- same_length2([_|L], L).
false.

?- same_length2(L, [_,_|L]).
false.

?- same_length2([_,_|L], L).
false.

?- same_length2(non_list, non_list).
false.

?- same_length2([a,b,c], [1,2,3]).
true.

?- same_length2([1|L], [3,4,5|R]).
L = [_, _],
R = [] ;
L = [_, _, _],
R = [_] ;
L = [_, _, _, _],
R = [_, _] ;

% Increasingly slow
?- time(same_length2(L1, L2)).
% 1 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (61% CPU, 116455 Lips)
L1 = L2, L2 = [] ;
% 13 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (87% CPU, 729354 Lips)
L1 = [_],
L2 = [_] ;
% 15 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (82% CPU, 795123 Lips)
L1 = [_, _],
L2 = [_, _] ;
% 19 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (82% CPU, 1558399 Lips)
L1 = [_, _, _],
L2 = [_, _, _] ;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
same_length2(L1, L2) :-
    lists2_end_len(L1, E1, Len1, L2, E2, Len2),
    % If ends are same, the length before the ends must be same
    (   E1 == E2
    % == is fastest portable integer comparison in swi-prolog
    ->  Len1 == Len2,
        same_length(E1, E2)
    ;   same_length(L1, L2)
    ). 

lists2_end_len(L1, E1, Len1, L2, E2, Len2) :-
    lists2_end_len_(L1, E1, _, 0, Len1Calc, L2, E2, _, 0, Len2Calc),
    Len1 = Len1Calc,
    Len2 = Len2Calc.
    
% Not using '$skip_list', to be portable
lists2_end_len_(L, E, Cl, U, Len, L2, E2, Cl2, U2, Len2) :-
    (   \+ \+ L = []
    % Found end of list
    ->  E = L,
        Len = U,
        (   L == []
        ->  Cl = true,
            % Can fail fast if other list is longer
            (   integer(U2)
            ->  U >= U2
            )
        ;   Cl = false
        ),
        (   nonvar(Len2)
        % Both lists traversed
        ->  true
        ;   lists2_end_len_(L2, E2, Cl2, U2, Len2, L, E, Cl, U, Len)
        )
    ;   L = [_|T],
        % Occurs check 
        T \== L,
        U1 is U + 1,
        lists2_end_len_(L2, E2, Cl2, U2, Len2, T, E, Cl, U1, Len)
    ).
```

Results in swi-prolog:

```
?- length(L, 10_000_000), time(same_length2(L, [])).
% 6 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (89% CPU, 253336 Lips)
false.

?- freeze(R, R=[_|L]), same_length2(L, R).
false.

?- L = [_|L], same_length2(L, []).
false.

?- same_length2([1,2|L], [3,4,5|L]).
false.

?- same_length2(L, [_|L]).
false.

?- same_length2(L, [_,_|L]).
false.

?- same_length2([_|L], L).
false.

?- same_length2([_,_|L], L).
false.

?- same_length2(non_list, non_list).
false.

?- same_length2([a,b,c], [1,2,3]).
true.

?- same_length2(L1, L2).
L1 = L2, L2 = [] ;
L1 = [_],
L2 = [_] ;
L1 = [_, _],
L2 = [_, _] ;

?- same_length2([1|L], [3,4,5|R]).
L = [_, _],
R = [] ;
L = [_, _, _],
R = [_] ;
L = [_, _, _, _],
R = [_, _] ;
```

Comment: `?- same_length2([1,2|L],[3,4,5|L]).   loops.`

Comment: `?- L=[_|L], same_length2(L,[]).   loops.`

Comment: Also note that `=@=` is non-portable.

Comment: Is `L=[_|L]` a fair test? Works with `occurs_check` enabled.

Comment: Take `length(L,10000000)` instead to see the very same problem. Since rational trees are the common default. Like SWI.

Comment: `?- freeze(R,R=[_|L]), same_length2(L,R).    loops.`

Comment: Fixed for `L=[_|L]` and `freeze`, using `same_term` and `\+ \+`.

Comment: Fixed for `length(L, 10_000_000)` using `lists2_end_len`.

Comment: Improved performance with `length(L, 10_000_000)`.

Comment: `s/\+ same_term(T, L),/T\==L/`

Comment: Switched to `\==` instead of `same_term`, for portability.